# fatal error during installation of chamilo

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, composer-php, chamilo-lms

I want to install chamilo in 1and1 when I transfer all the files that I downloaded via FTP to the official site so after I have linked to the subdomain it works an error:

```
Fatal error: require (): Failed opening required /homepages/...../ chamilo / vendor / composer /../ symfony / polyfill-mbstring / bootstrap.php '(include_path ='.: / Usr / lib / php5.6 ') in
Chamilo / vendor / composer / autoload_real.php on line 66
```

I tried to proceed differently by sending it from ssh but the server of 1and1 does not recognize the command sudo

If anyone can help me find the solution

Comment: Have you ran `composer install` before upload?

Comment: I installed composer  after the upload and I put them under the www folder of the server should  I do it under  the folder chamilo???? i need help please

Answer (score 1):

Given the type of error you are getting, it looks like you are trying to install Chamilo directly from its development sources at https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms (maybe even from the master branch which is not install-ready yet).

You should try to use either a stable package (from the "Releases" tab on Github) or download the 1.11.x development branch (which is install-ready at this date - obviously the master branch will get that soon as well), but in this case you need to read the README.md file carefully as it requires additional steps (namely using `composer update` as kind of hinted by @eRiz.

Answer (score 0):

This means you downloaded a zip file directly from Github.
You need to install composer in order to generate the "vendor" folder.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx

Then call "composer install"

Or you can download the official package here:

https://chamilo.org/chamilo-lms/#downloads